# How to perform select query across server, schema, and database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two schemas in PostgreSQL, let's say schema A and schema B.

In schema A, I need to select query like below

```
select start_date, End_date, activity_desc 
from transaction_table 
where start_date <= to_timestamp(to_char(date(current_date),'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'YYYY/MM/DD') + interval '06:59:59.9999' 
  and start_date>= to_timestamp(to_char(date(current_date) - interval '1 day','YYYY/MM/DD'), 'YYYY/MM/DD') + interval '16:00:00.0001'
```

The result of the query above needs to be inserted into the table in schema B like below

```
insert into tableB1 (start_date, End_date, activity_desc) 
values (refers from select query above)
```

The point is, a select query from the table transaction at schema A will be executed every 15 minutes.

If this were MSSQL, I'd know how to solve it, but in PostgreSQL, I don't know.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `to_timestamp(to_char(date(current_date),'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'YYYY/MM/DD') + interval '06:59:59.9999' ` can be simplified to `current_date + interval '06:59:59.9999'` and the second expression can be simplified to `current_date - 1 + interval '16:00:00.0001'`

Comment: If both schemas are in the same database, then just do `insert into schema_b.tableb1 (...) select .... from schema_a.transaction_table`

Comment: how about different DB & Server ?